# Index every column to add foreign keys

Tags: mysql, indexing, foreign-keys

I am currently learning about foreign keys and trying to add them as much as I can in my application to ensure data-integrity. I am using INNODB on Mysql.

My `clicks` table has a structure something like...

`id, timestamp, link_id, user_id, ip_id, user_agent_id, ...` etc for about 12 _id columns.

Obviously these all point to other tables, so should I add a foreign key on them? MySQL is creating an index automatically for every foreign key, so essentially I'll have an index on every column? Is this what I want?

FYI - this table will essentially be my most bulky table. My research basically tells me I'm sacrificing performance for integrity but doesn't suggest how harsh the performance drop will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right before inserting such a row, you did 12 inserts or lookups to get the ids, correct?  Then, as you do the `INSERT`, it will do 12 checks to verify that all of those ids have a match.  Why bother; you just verified them with the code.

Sure, have FKs in development.  But in production, you should have weeded out all the coding mistakes, so FKs are a waste.

A related tip -- Don't do all the work at once.  Put the raw (not-yet-normalized) data into a staging table.  Periodically do bulk operations to add new normalization keys and get the _id's back.  *Then* move them into the 'real' table.  This has the added advantage of decreasing the interference with reads on the table.  If you are expecting more than 100 inserts/second, let's discuss further.

Answer (score 0):

The generic answer is that if you considered a data item so important that you created a lookup table for the possible values, then you should create a foreign key relationship to ensure you are not getting any orphan records.

However, you should reconsider, whether all data items (fields) in your clicks table need a lookup table. For example `ip_id` field probably represents an IP address. You can simply store the IP address directly in the clicks table, you do not really need a lookup table, since IP addresses have a wide range and the IP addresses are unique.

Based on the re-evaluation of the fields, you may be able to reduce the number of related tables, thus the number of foreign keys and indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Here are three things to consider:

1. What is the ratio of reads to writes on this table? If you are reading much more often than writing, then more indexes could be good, but if it is the other way around then the cost of maintaining those indexes becomes harder to bear.
2. Are some of the foreign keys not very selective? If you have an index on the `gender_id` column then it is probably a waste of space. My general rule is that indexes without included columns should have about 1000 distinct values (unless values are unique) and then tweak from there.
3. Are some foreign keys rarely or never going to be used as a filter for a query? If you have a `last_modified_user_id` field but you never have any queries that will return a list of items which were last modified by a particular user then an index on that field is less useful.

A little bit of knowledge about indexes can go a long way. I recommend http://use-the-index-luke.com